# Why does the object appear behind the other object when i move the camera

Tags: modeling, camera

When i move the camera some object appear behind my character[image][image]
[image]

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: i just addet it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body has its *In Front* option activated, so it will always appear in front of the other ones (in the viewport, not in render), disable this option:

[image]